# Why isn't my function throttled?

Tags: javascript, meteor, underscore.js

I'm trying to have notificationError throttled, only called at most once per second. For some reason, it's never called, even though notificationErrorThrottled is.

```
var notificationError = function () {
    console.log(`title: ${notification_title}; body: ${notification_body}`)
    Notifications.error(notification_title, notification_body);
};

global.notificationErrorThrottled = function (title, body) {
    global.notification_title = title;
    global.notification_body = body;
    _.throttle(notificationError, 1000, {trailing: false});
}
```

Here's similar code that works (with _.once instead of _.throttle):

```
var notificationUS = function () {
    Notifications.warn('US style?', "If you want to use moneylines, prefix them with '+' or '-'. Otherwise they are considered decimal odds.");
};

global.notificationUSonce = _.once(notificationUS);
```

This is how I call the global functions from another file:

```
notificationUSonce();
notificationErrorThrottled('Nope.', "Please check your input.");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Underscores `_.throttle` will return a new function that you should call. In the same way as you do with `notificationUSonce()`.
Right now you never call the actual throttled version of `notificationError()`.

```
var throttledFunction = _.throttle(notificationError, 1000, {trailing: false});

global.notificationErrorThrottled = function (title, body) {
    global.notification_title = title;
    global.notification_body = body;
    throttledFunction();
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't have guessed that in a million years. Thanks mate. Code works.